# How to change text color based on background color of sibling element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an effect similar to the one described here https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/. The problem is that one of my background elements is not parent of the text element I'm trying to change color, producing an undesired result and I can't figure out how to achieve the effect I want. The result I'm getting is the one shown in this image:
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKe2v.png)

I want the text over the green tilted band to be white, while the text over the white area be green as it is. I have tried putting inside the green-band div but it gets clipped or distorted when I add the tilt effect to the band (with clip-path or skewX). The code used to get the result shown in the image is the following:

```css
#green-band {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #9DC42E;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

#green-band~h1 {
  color: #623BD1;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

#green-band~h3 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <div id="green-band"></div>
      <h1 class="">UBICACIÓN ESTRATÉGICA</h1>
      <h3 class="text-gray mt-5 font-italic">A solo 10 minutos del centro Pereira</h3>
      <h3 class="text-gray mt-5 font-italic">Cerca al aeropuerto</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
      <img src="images/cargando.gif" data-src="images/mapa.png" class="img-fluid lazy" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to find a solution for some hours but nothing, so I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try in the #green-band~h1 just put white in color.

Comment: I tried that but what I get is the text over the white background in black and the text over the green band in something near to purple

Answer (score 0):

```css
#green-band {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #9DC42E;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

#green-band~h1 {
  color: #623BD1;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

#green-band~h3 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <div id="green-band"></div>
      <h1 class="">UBICACIÓN ESTRATÉGICA</h1>
      <h3 class="text-gray mt-5 font-italic">A solo 10 minutos del centro Pereira</h3>
      <h3 class="text-gray mt-5 font-italic">Cerca al aeropuerto</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
      <img src="images/cargando.gif" data-src="images/mapa.png" class="img-fluid lazy" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use mix-blend-mode: color-dodge; 
It worked for me.

Comment: I tried changing the mix-blend mode to color-dodge in #green-band~h1 but what I get is all the text in white, meaning that only the part over the green band is seen.
I don't know why my result is different from the code snippet in your answer, in which the text over the green band is white (as we want) but the text over the white background is purple

Comment: For that you need to set the color what you want on that class/id where you're using mix-blend-mode.